# Is it proper to call your partner “Mädchen” or “Junge”?

Tags: word-usage, colloquial

For example, it’s common among many English speakers to refer to their female partners as girls (e.g., *that is my girl*). So is it also acceptable in German to claim, for example, “das ist mein Mädchen” when referring to your lady lover (similarly for *Junge,* if it’s your male lover); or would this come across as crude—or worse, perverted?

Comment: By the way, "mein Mädchen" is what German Chancellor Kohl used to (somewhat condescendingly) call Angela Merkel back in the days.

Comment: And you when one say to a man "mein freund" it would be gayish,but some people say to me "hi,mein Freund! Wie geht's?

Comment: @user1474062 No, I can’t confirm that assumption.

Comment: @Stefan Walter That is gold.

Comment: Related: [How to distinguish between a female friend and a girlfriend?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/1039/1859) · [What is the equivalent of “boyfriend” in German?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/5028/1859)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is pretty, if not completely unusual to use **Mädchen** or **Junge** when referring to your girlfriend or boyfriend. You might do that jokingly or ironically, but even then I’d say it would sound a bit weird. **Mädchen** seems very old fashioned and may suggest that you don’t see your partner really as a grown-up, **Junge** would be used by mothers to refer to their sons.

**Freund** and **Freundin** are the most common words used to refer to your partner. **Partner**/**Partnerin** are much less common but completely acceptable. **Lebensgefährte**/**Lebensgefährtin** is typically German in that it is a monster of a word, but you can use it (you should be above forty years of age, though).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I can see how using Mädchen in reference to your girlfriend could be seen as unusual. In fact, on an anecdotal basis I see more guys calling their girlfriends "girls" than girls calling their boyfriends "boys" (in America), usually preferring "man." I suppose it could come across as sexist.

Comment: "Lebensgefährte" is used for long-term marriage-like relationships regardless of age. Both "Partner" and "Lebensgefährte" sound sterile compared to "Freund" and are used in situations where this is deemed appropriate.

Comment: Good answer. I would like to add that calling your girlfriend *mein Mädchen* would not sound perverted as in my girlfriend is underage.

Comment: I read "Lebensgefährte" today in a magazine ad under "Sie sucht ihn" (W4M, women seeking men). The age bracket was 35 to 65 or so, if that gives some context.

Answer (score 6):

Back in the day, say 1950s rock’n’roll youth culture, possessive pronoun plus *Mädchen* (or *Mädel*) may have been normal, as would have been *Puppe, Baby/-e, Süße, Perle, Schnecke, Schnitte, Schnalle, Tusse, Ische*, maybe also *Fräulein* or *Frauchen*. For the other sex, however, one would never have used *Junge* the same way (and neither *Knabe* or *Bube*), preferring instead stronger male nouns like *Kerl, Macker, Typ, Stecher*.

More obvious and individual sexual metaphors would be used where appropriate, i.e. mostly by third persons or in private.

There are some words applicable to both genders and even in marriage, e.g. *Alte(r) / Olle(r)* or *Liebste(r)*. In many cases, though, people will just use *Freund(in)* or *Frau* and *Mann*. The latter may not require marriage nowadays, i.e. it’s not necessarily short for *Ehefrau* and *Ehemann* any more.

In more formal or legal texts and depending on the officially recognized level of the relationship one will find other designations, of course, like *Lebensgefährte* or *Lebensabschnittsgefährte* “LAG” (but rarely just *Gefährte*), *Partner* or *(eingetragener) Lebenspartner*, *Gatte* or *Ehegatte*, *Gemahl*, *Angetrauter*, *Verlobter*, *Geliebter* or *Liebling*. (Add *+in* or *+e* for female version, of course.) Interestingly, *Braut* can be used more freely – as in *Rockerbraut* – than *Bräutigam*, which is of course a sign of sexism.

Answer (score 4):

*Mein Mädchen* ist in einigen Milieus durchaus üblich, *mein Junge* dagegen soweit mir bekannt ist nicht, und zwar weil Frauen eher verniedlicht werden als Männer, für die eine ähnliche Form aber *mein Kerl* wäre.

Weil die Verniedlichungsformen für Frauen oft als problematisch empfunden werden, sind sie aber in vielen Milieus auch eher tabu. Je kleiner und privater der Kreis ist, desto eher sind sie möglich. Wo man nicht das geschlechtsübergreifende *mein Schatz* sagen würde, weil es zu privat klingt, würde man auch *Mädchen* und *Kerl* vermeiden.

Die Jugendsprache verwendet sehr oft immer neue Formen, auch *boy* und *girl* konnte man eine zeitlang hören, aber Personen, die mit einer Mode groß geworden sind behalten diese gerne bei.

Krude und pervers ist beides nicht, aber womöglich kommt es altmodisch oder distanzlos rüber. Freund/Freundin sind wohl die neutralsten Formulierungen. Ansonsten hängt viel vom Milieu und eigenen Alter ab. Immer die gängige Jugendsprache zu verwenden, obwohl man selbst 80 ist, kann unpassender wirken als eine veraltete Form zu wählen. Aber eine 80jährige kann in der richtigen Umgebung auch fröhlich ihren 82jährigen Feund als 'mein Boyfriend' vorstellen, wenn sie gerade mit dieser jugendlichen Konnotation spielen will.

Answer (score 3):

There is a implication present in each of the two possibilities that probably although somewhat unconsciously stop a German from using *mein Mädchen/Junge* for their girl-/boyfriends apart from both sounding somehow like *my daughter/son.*

For *Mädchen,* it is that that can also be understood as *Dienstmädchen* or *Küchenmädchen* both of which imply a master/servant relationship rather than two lovers. That is also part of the reason why chancellor Kohl’s ‘mein Mädchen’ towards Angela Merkel sounded so condescendingly, and is a reason why you should never use that term in the presence of feminists.

For *Junge,* that word is not used all across Germany to mean *boy.* In the South-East of Germany, one would use *Bub* or *Bua* (the latter being dialectal). However, these terms scream *child* even more than a plain *Junge* would — incidentally, I remember a local newspaper article thanking three unknown *Buben* for helping a person who had a heart attack. Two days later, their identity was revealed as 15 to 16-year olds, which prompted the newspaper to take back the *Buben* of before.

In areas where *Junge* is used to mean *boy,* you *still* would not use it towards your boyfriend though; maybe it is still too child-sounding, or maybe it doesn’t fit with the strong/male implications Alexander mentioned.

Comment: Although I personally wouldn't use it, I don't think referring to one's girlfriend as "mein Mädl " (or "Madl" in parts of Bavaria) is that uncommon.

Comment: I didn’t mean for the answer to mean ‘strictly don’t use’ but rather ‘very uncommon at least’. Personally, I can’t remember any of my mates from school using *Madl.*

Comment: I fully agree with you that using "mein Mädchen" is pretty much impossible. But somehow the situation seems different with "Mädl" - probably because "Mit den Mädls weggehen" is fairly commonly used - mainly for girls going out with their girlfriends, but it could be used by guys as well. It somehow seems to have lost the connotation of "Mädchen", and can be used pretty much like the English "girl". (But still, I find its use to describe one's girlfriend a bit derogatory).

Comment: @Gerhard Oh yes, that’s pretty much true: When referring to *friends* it’s often *die Mädls* or *die Jungs* that one goes to meet. But the question specifically asked for partners.

Answer (score 2):

At least **mein Mädchen** doesn’t sound too wrong. Although it is a bit of a slang phrase and right now the only situation I can imagine where somebody says it completely serious would be a talk between guys with a sentence like **das ist mein Mädchen.** **Junge** on the other side sounds wrong to me in the context of a relationship. It’s probably one of these terms where the relation in terms of *strong, male* vs. *weak, female* should be emphasised.

It is certainly not used in the broad public and usually it is rather used for children by their parents.

Funnily enough, once you grow older it’s totally normal to call your husband and wife **mein Mann** and **meine Frau.**