# Übersetzung von "I like her as a friend"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

> I like her as a friend.

Wie kann man das ins Deutsche übersetzen? Wenn man als

> Ich mag sie wie eine Freundin.

übersetzt, dann ist es nicht klar, ob mit "Freundin" eine feste Freundin gemeint ist.

Comment: Related: [How to distinguish between a female friend and a girlfriend?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1039/how-to-distinguish-between-a-female-friend-and-a-girlfriend)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In German, you will quite often stumble over the question of an appropriate term to express the degree of a relationship (but English isn't much clearer, IMHO, if you consider terms like "lady-friend").

If you go with a straight translation

> - Ich mag sie als Freundin.

you are somewhat vague as to the amount of romance involved. What *kind* of "friend" remains unclear.

> - Ich mag sie als **eine** Freundin.

With "eine", the "uniqueness" (implied in friend=girlfriend) is excluded, meaning this girl is *most likely* simply a pal.

Once you add a tiny qualifier, suddenly the relationship becomes clear:

> - Ich mag sie **nur/bloß/lediglich** als Freundin.

(Just for the sake of completeness:)
If you *want* to be romanticly involved, you'd say:

> - Ich möchte/mag sie **zur** Freundin (haben).

Answer (score 2):

Man übersetzt es je nach Kontext. Wenn gemeint ist "I don't want a relationship with her, just friendship" ist der natürliche Ausdruck "wir sind nur befreundet." Alles mit "ich mag sie als ..." klingt nach Anglizismus.

Answer (score 1):

`I like her as a friend` is translated as:

> Ich mag sie als Freundin.

Comment: What is the difference between *als* and *wie eine*?